# Will it be an issue if I create a model in rails for the join table that was created through habtm?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-and-belongs-to-many

Consider the following:

I have a model Tags and Post.

There is a habtm relationship created such that I have **models_tags** table created.

Will it cause a problem if I create a model for the join table(**models_tags**)?

Answer (score 0):

It won't work without adjustments.

HABTM join tables don't have an `id` column, which you would need to add and make work.

You'd also have to have the model called `ModelsTag` unless you wanted to rename the table also.

Comment: So it's never possible to add data to a table with no Id column in RoR is it?

Answer (score -1):

Its not a problem,  just add a ModelTag model, and use has_many and through option